# Miklos Schweitzer 2013, Strong lower bound on sumset $|A+qA|$,

Tags: inequality

Let $q$ be a positive integer. Prove there exists a constant $C_q$ such that the following inequality holds for any finite set $A$ of integers:
$$|A+qA|\ge (q+1)|A|-C_q.$$
This is a problem from Miklos Schweitzer 2013. I tried to use the fact $|A+B|\ge |A|+|B|-1$ but no avail. Here $A+qA=\{a+qa^{\prime} | a,a^{\prime}\in A \}$. Any help? I am looking for an elementary solution.